# DXL in batch mode

Tags: ibm-doors

I am facing issues with running DXL in batch mode

doors: assertion failed, line 3173, document.cpp: !nls_("unexpected: tree root does not have a name attribute") stack:

my batch file is as below

```
set arg1=%1
        set arg2=%2
        set arg1=%arg1:"=%
        set arg2=%arg2:"=%
        start "DOORS" "C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors.exe" -d ABCD  -u xxxxx  -P xxxx -b "C:\\doNothing.dxl" -dxl "string s_ModListPath = \"%arg1%\";string CRNUM = \"%arg2%\";#include <C:\\Users\\ObjectsList.dxl>"
```

I run this batch file from command line by passing arguments as below

```
C:\Users\ObjectsCmnd.bat C:\\TEMP\\ModulesSelected.txt 12345
```

Please suggest me what wrong I am doing and why I am getting the error

OBjectList.dxl

```
pragma encoding, "UTF-8"
pragma runLim,0
Buffer b_ModPath

string s_ModPath
string s_Log = "C:\\TEMP\\ObjectList.txt"
string s_OutPutLog = "C:\\TEMP\\MDPRLog.txt"

Object o

bool b1 = canOpenFile(s_ModListPath,false)
bool b2 = canOpenFile(s_Log,true)
bool b3 = canOpenFile(s_OutPutLog,true)

if(!b1)
{
    print  "cannot open file to read the module list \n"
}
if(!b2)
{
    print "cannot open file to write the objectlist \n"
}
if(!b3)
{
    print "cannot open file to write the MDPRlog under temp"
}

Stream st = read s_ModListPath
Stream Output = write s_Log
Stream Log = write s_OutPutLog


void fn_Main()
{   
    while(!end st)
    {
        b_ModPath = create
        st >= b_ModPath
        s_ModPath = stringOf(b_ModPath)

        Module m = read(s_ModPath,false) 
        if(null m)
        {
            Log << "null module path "  s_ModPath "\n"
            continue
        }
        //noError()
        current = m

        if(!exists(attribute("Change_Request_ID")))
        {
            Log << "Attr Change_Request_ID doesnt exist in module " s_ModPath "\n"
            continue
        }
        if(!null m)
        {
            //current = m
            Filter CRObjects = contains(attribute "Change_Request_ID",CRNUM,false)  && attribute "CC_Status" == "Frozen"
            set (m, CRObjects, acceptedObjs, rejectedObjs)
            filtering on
            if  (acceptedObjs <= 0)
            {
                Log << "No objects that contain CR and CC_Staus frozen \n"      
            }
            for o in m do
            {           
                    Output << fullName(m) ";" identifier(o) "\n"
            }
            filtering off
        }
        else
        {
            Log << "Null module " s_ModPath "\n"
        }
        close m
    }
    delete b_ModPath    
}
fn_Main()
Log << "-------- ObjectList Completed ------------- \n"
close st
close Log
close Output
```

Comment: Without any further information or the source code, one can only guess. In the best case, you access information that is not available in batch mode, in the worst case, you have a corrupted DOORS Module. Try to narrow down the root cause, e.g. by using print commands or cout, and try to find out exactly which line of code causes the problem, whether only a specific module or view or attribute is affected

Comment: this problem is occurring when the module is huge, please find the scripts attached,doNothing.dxl is empty to run the coammnd in batch mode i added this

Comment: I am not able to attach the code

Comment: the problem is occuring when i run only in batch mode, if I wont use -b in command line then it is working fine without any errors

Comment: Found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56229908/what-are-some-common-reasons-for-why-a-dxl-script-would-work-in-doors-but-not-wh