# What are some common reasons for why a DXL script would work in DOORS but not when it's run in batch mode?

Tags: ibm-doors

I have a dxl script that works when run in the DOORS application but does not work when it's run in batch mode. I am not sure why this would be. When running in batch mode I get the following error:

doors: assertion failed, line 3173, document.cpp: !nls_("unexpected: tree root does not have a name attribute") stack

I know that creating a GUI and things like that might cause this error but I am not doing that. The odd thing is that the script stops running in different modules and different parts in the modules. So the script breaks down in different areas of DOORS everytime run.

Here is what I think is the relevant code that might be causing the error in batch mode:

```
Buffer bsz = create

void addNewLineSeparator(Buffer& b)
{
if (length(b) > 0)
{
    b += "\n"
}
}

void display(string s)
{
addNewLineSeparator(bsz)
    bsz += s
}

void displayRich(string s)
{
addNewLineSeparator(bsz)
    bsz += s
}

void displayRichWithColour(string s)
{
addNewLineSeparator(bsz)
    bsz += s
}

void displayRichWithColor(string s)
{
addNewLineSeparator(bsz)
    bsz += s
}

void display(Attr__ a)
{
string s = richText a
    if (!null s)
    {
        displayRich s
    }
}

string showOut(Object o, int depth) {
Link l
    LinkRef lr
    ModName_ otherMod = null
    Module linkMod = null
    ModuleVersion otherVersion = null
    Object othero
    string disp = null
    string s = null
    string plain, plainDisp
    int plainTextLen
    int count
    bool doneOne = false
    string linkModName = "*"
    for l in all(o->linkModName) do {
        otherVersion = targetVersion l
            otherMod = module(otherVersion)
            if (null otherMod || isDeleted otherMod) continue
                othero = target l
                if (null othero) {
                    load(otherVersion, false)
                }
        othero = target l
            if (null othero) continue
                if (isDeleted othero) continue
                    doneOne = true
                    if (depth == 1) {
                        s = fullName(otherMod)
                            if (isBaseline(otherVersion)) {
                                s = s " [" versionString(otherVersion) "]"
                            }
                        if (s == "")
                            displayRich("\\pard " " ")
                        else
                            displayRich("\\pard " s)
                    }
    }
return s
}
for o in m do
    {
        print showOut(o, 1)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen with anything that might be reliant on a view. Batch mode for DOORS can be finicky. Also, DOORS is not exactly careful about memory management- if you can, it might make more sense to have your code split into sections, one of which runs a lightweight set that runs other code inside of an 'eval_' function. That will help keep memory de-allocation running more smoothly (a trick I used to do a full link inventory of our database- over 16000 modules opened and closed!)

To respond to your edit:

The code you are showing is Layout DXL, which is evaluated when a view is displayed- specifically, the 'displayRich' function is trying to take a richtext string and put it into the appropriate column- but that column doesn't exist, as the view context is not created in batch mode.

A simple fix would be to wrap your entire code in:

```
if(!isBatch){
     // Your Code Here
}
```

This will ensure that the DXL is only calculated if the user is running DOORS in non-batch mode.

Comment: I added a bit of what my code looks like. Do you see any memory allocation issues or something that might be reliant on a view?

Comment: So is the only way for the script to work if I don't run it in batch mode? Sorry I don't understand how isBatch helps. I tried wrapping the script around the if statement and I am still getting the same error when running in batch mode.

Comment: Sorry, small error. Try:  !isBatch instead. You want the if statement to evaluate as false if the code is running In a batch context.

Comment: If the if statement evaluates as false, then my code will not run in batch mode right? Wrapping it in !isBatch and running it in batch mode made the script just not execute essentially(which makes sense). Is there anyway for the script to work in batch mode?

Comment: Yes- ish.

Right now, your script is grabbing the links it sees and putting a dynamic list of them into the column that the script is called from.

You would want to change the script to attribute DXL (since layout dxl may not be evaluated correctly in your batch system ) and change the 'display' commands to something like obj.attrDXLName = richText ( s )

This would be a significant re-write, however.